# Web API file transfer unauthorized error

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I'm writing a simple Web API application using ASP.NET MVC 5 and Web API v2. The api should receive a binary file from a client that uses `HttpClient` in a Winforms application. The application and the web site should be running on a closed network with Active Directory.

The controller:

```
[Route("FileTest"]
public HttpResponseMessage PostTest([FromBody]HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
    // does nothing just retuns ok
}
```

The client:

```
public void SendFile(string fileName)
{
     using(FileStream fileStream  = new FileStream(fileName, fileMode.open, FilleAccess.read))
     {
        using(MultipartFormDataContent data = new MultipartFormDataContent ())
        {
           using(StreamContent streamcontent = new StreamContent(fileStream))
           {
                data.Add(streamcontent );
                HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
                res = client .PostAsync("address", data).Result;
                res.EnsureSucessStatusCode();   // exception unauthorized
           }
         }
     }
```

Why is this not working?

Comment: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/working-with-http/sending-html-form-data,-part-2

Answer (score 0):

HttpPostedFileBase is a MVC class, it is not a Web API class, so it is unlikely they will work together.

Instead of trying to pass the file as a parameter, just read the request content as a stream.

```
[Route("FileTest"]
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> PostTest(HttpRequestMessage request)
{
    var stream = await request.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But how do i get the file details? like the file name and lengt? dows my code at the client is ok? what if i want to send files from web pages?

Comment: @user3404887 The length is in request.Content.Headers.ContentLength and you can set the ContentDisposition header to pass the filename.